# How do you get the value from Func<t> called async?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, func

How do you get the value from a `Func<t>` that is called using BeginInvoke?

For example:

```
private void MyTest()
{
    Func<string> foo = Bar;

    foo.BeginInvoke(BarComplete, null);
}

private string Bar()
{
    return "Success";
}

private void BarComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var result = (string) ar.AsyncState;

    Console.WriteLine(result); // Should print "Success"
}
```

Do I have to cast this to an AsyncCallback and then call `EndInvoke`?

Anyways, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: If simply calling `Invoke()` is an option, that would work too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncState` holds the `null` you passed in as a 2nd parameter, you should pass the `foo` object in instead. To get the result you must call `EndInvoke` from the foo object and it will return a object version of the result.

```
private void MyTest()
{
    Func<string> foo = Bar;

    foo.BeginInvoke(BarComplete, foo);
}

private string Bar()
{
    return "Success";
}

private void BarComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var foo = (Func<string>)ar.AsyncState;
    var uncastResult = foo.EndInvoke(ar); //This returns a "object", but it would still work with WriteLine
    var castResult = (string)uncastResult;

    Console.WriteLine(uncastResult); // Should print "Success"
    Console.WriteLine(castResult); // Should also print "Success"
}
```

Comment: Where is `foo` coming from in `BarComplete`. He doesn't exist in that scope, right?

Comment: In `BarComplete`, can't you just call `foo()` and get a `string`? at that point, it's a regular `Func<string>`.

Comment: @vlad no, because that would be a 2nd invocation of foo, we are trying to get the result from the first invocation. In this trivial example it does not many any sense to do it asynchronously, but if a `Thread.Sleep(1000000)` was inside `Bar()` it would make sense.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain right, I just realized this through some LINQPad and Joe Albahari's Threading in C# ebook. My mistake.